# preg match if found exclude that string php

Tags: php

I am stuck in a very simple PHP problem.
I am having a string as `$a = "123 text";` or it can also be `$a="lorem ipsum 1234 dummy text";`

I want that the output shall be  `$a="text";` or  `$a="lorem ipsum dummy text";`
In short I want to exclude the number that can either be **123** or **12345** or anything else.

I have tried   `$except_txt = "text 123456 dummy"; 
                            $pattern = "/12/"; 
                            $replacement = "";
                            $path = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $except_txt);`

but I get output as `$except_txt = "text 3456 dummy";`

Comment: Are you just trying to remove numbers that start with 12?

Comment: Make your pattern so it removes all clusters of digits, not just "12". Try for instance `/\d+/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet solves your problem:

```
$a = "lorem ipsum 1234 dummy text";
$a = preg_replace("/[\d]/", "", $a);
echo $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
preg_replace("/(\d)+/", "", $except_txt);
```